# Linhas ao lado em css

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar linhas ao lado de uma palavra, mas quando entro em resolução mobile, as linhas sobem e ficam desalinhadas. Como faço de modo que elas fiquem verticalmente alinhadas e do mesmo comprimento horizontal?

Primeira resolução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segunda resolução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div class="e-mais">
<p>E MAIS</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
       .e-mais {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #c78b2f;
        }
        .e-mais p:before, .e-mais p:after {
            content: ' ';
            position: absolute;
            width: 5%;
            border-top: 1px solid #c78b2f;
            margin-top: 1.4%;
        }

        .e-mais p:before {
            margin-left: -63px;
        }

        .e-mais p:after {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    .e-mais p:before, .e-mais p:after {
        margin-top: 1.7%
    }
    .e-mais p:before {
        margin-left: -53px;
    }
    .row.escolas {
        margin-top: 46px;
    }
}
```

Comment: poste seu HTML tambem  por favor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cara para esse tipo de coisa a minha dica é vc usar a fonte em `REM` e os elementos em `EM`.

Com isso vc tem uma medida relativa que funciona assim. `1REM` é `=` a `16px`, então se vc tem a `font` com `1rem` e o `::after` com `2em` a font vai ter `16px` e o `::after 32px`. Já se a `font` tiver `1rem` e o `::after 0.5em` ele vai ter na verdade `8px`, então `EM` é relativo ao `REM` que está no pai entende. Para ficar mais fácil de entender veja o modelo mais abaixo.

**Repare como tudo cresce proporcional devido as medidas dos *pseudo-elementos* estarem atreladas a medida do `font-size` do `pai REM` / `filho EM*`*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem assim.

```css
.texto {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 8px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.texto::before,
.texto::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.65em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.05em;
  background-color: red;
  left: -1.25em;
}
.texto::after {
  left: initial;
  right: -1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">Meu texto</div>
<br>
<div class="texto" style="font-size: 2rem">Meu texto</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado!

Comment: @FernandoFigueiredo sem problemas meu caro! Se vc achar que resolveu o problema lembre-se de marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas da resposta :)